# Retrieve wordpress posts with featured image via SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using this query in a PHP script outside Wordpress to retrieve entries with their featured images

```
SELECT  ( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS url 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'
```

...and it works fine.

But this way I get full-size image URL. I need to retrieve 'medium' or 'thumbnail' sizes of these images.

¿Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

here is the response :

```
SELECT TITRE,DESCR,URL, CONCAT(LEFT(IMG, LENGTH(IMG) - LOCATE('.', 
REVERSE(IMG))),'-150x150.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(IMG, '.', -1)) AS IMG FROM (
SELECT    
p.`post_title` AS TITRE, 
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `post_id` = p.`ID` and `meta_key`='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc') AS DESCR,
p.`guid` AS URL,
(SELECT `guid` FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value) AS IMG
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id') TT

where DESCR is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query, adapted from the above, solved my particular problem which was simply to grab the last four posts and their featured images. Plus the post_name from which I could construct a pretty URL

```
SELECT title, post_name, date, content, CONCAT(LEFT(image, LENGTH(image) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(image))),'-150x150.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(image, '.', -1)) AS image
FROM (
  SELECT    
  p.post_title AS title, 
  p.post_status AS 'status', 
  p.post_date AS date,
  p.post_content AS content,
  p.post_name AS post_name,
  (SELECT `guid` FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value) AS image
  FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
  WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND p.id = m.post_id
  AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 4
) TT
```

Of course from there it's easy to make an excerpt etc using:

```
for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++){  
  $post_content = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "content"); 
  $post_excerpt = substr($post_content, 0, 90); 
  $post_permalink = $post_url . mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_name");

  echo $post_permalink; //etc

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query for thumbnail size , for medium image i am not sure about the right size if you know the dimension then make custom alias as i made below using the [**SUBSTRING_INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the extension of file then i have used  [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function with the `post_name` column and the dimensions + extension ,similarly you can do this for medium size , As all upload goes to the upload folder   you can analyze the generated thumbs name are `original attachment name + -150x150 or other dimensions` so from this logic your thumbs get the name with the dimensions, the attachments of post are stored in post_meta with the post id and having key name **_wp_attachment_metadata** which stores all the information about different sizes of file but in a serialized form so in mysql query you cannot unserialize the data

```
SELECT    
CONCAT(p.`post_name` ,'-150x150.',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(( SELECT `guid` FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ), '.', -1) )    
 AS `thumbnail`,
 (SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS `full`
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'
```

This query works for me to get thumbnail of size 150*150 hope it works for you also

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    
    p.ID,
    p.post_title AS title, 
    p.post_name AS post_name,
   (SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = m.meta_value and meta_key='_wp_attachment_metadata') AS meta_value
FROM 
    wp_posts p, 
    wp_postmeta m
WHERE
        p.post_type = 'post'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p.id = m.post_id
    AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
ORDER BY 
    p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

And then use unserialize PHP function with meta_value

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I was migrating wordpress data to a custom-made CRM, which required the posts and image meta in the same table. Wanted to share, hoping this might help someone in the future.

This following query gets the important columns from wp_posts and also the images and attachment metadata. Adjust it to your needs.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_date, p.post_content, p.post_title, p.post_excerpt, p.post_status, p.post_name, p.post_type, exm.meta_value AS image_url, exdata.meta_value AS image_metadata FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ex ON p.ID=ex.post_id AND ex.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta exm ON ex.meta_value=exm.post_id AND exm.meta_key='_wp_attached_file'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta exdata ON ex.meta_value=exdata.post_id AND exdata.meta_key='_wp_attachment_metadata'
WHERE p.post_status='publish' AND p.post_type='post'
```